# What ruse of danger prevents Muggles from exploring the area where Hogwarts and Hogsmeade stand?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, muggles

In *Goblet of Fire*, it says that people cannot see the school; rather, they see only ruins and several warnings of danger. (Chapter 11)

What kind of warnings make Muggles too afraid (or indifferent) to explore the false ruins in the enchanted area where the Hogwarts School and Hogsmeade stand?

Comment: Warning: Honey Badger Breeding Ground.

Comment: “Parking rates: 12 dollars each hour.”

Comment: @b_jonas £12 each hour

Comment: @b_jonas Hell, that's downright cheap around here.

Comment: Basicly, what you made me think was that, should Bear Grylls want, he'd find Hogwarts

Comment: @CandiedMango: $12 each hour. No other currency accepted.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm not sure that's a direct quotation from *Goblet of Fire*, at least I can't find it in my copy (Scholastic). I did find this, though:

> “It’s bewitched,” said Hermione. “If a Muggle looks at it, all they
>   see is a moldering old ruin with a sign over the entrance saying
>   **danger, do not enter, unsafe**.”
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* – chapter eleven: *Aboard The Hogwarts Express*</sub>

Also, from the same book:

> …“Ministry task force of five hundred have been working on it all year.
>   Muggle Repelling Charms on every inch of it. Every time Muggles have
>   got anywhere near here all year, they’ve suddenly remembered urgent
>   appointments and had to dash away again . . . bless them,” he [Arthur Weasley] added
>   fondly…
>
> <sub>Chapter eight: *The Quidditch World Cup*</sub>

Comment: The first wouldn't deter, I can say that from personal experience: A certain kind of person would *love* to explore that moldering old ruin, danger or no. The second sounds much more effective. ;-)

Comment: I'm interesting that you write "from the same book" and then quote two differing books.

Comment: Both are taken from Goblet of Fire.

Comment: It stands to reason there might be a ruin explorer who simply didn't have any urgent appointments.

Comment: @MarkRogers Oh but that's where magic comes in and either an appointment is created, or the muggle gets the idea that he needs to go back home. Anyway, I'd bet that along with "remembering an urgent appointment", the muggle's memory is modified too, so that he doesn't remember seeing Hogwarts.

Comment: For the sake of completeness it should be noted that the second quotation is referring to the Quidditch World Cup grounds, not Hogwarts, but presumably the same sort of thing is used in both.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a variant of the muggle-repelling charm.

Every inch of the Quidditch Trillenium Stadium had "Muggle-Repelling Charms on every inch of it. Every time Muggles have got anywhere near here all year, they've suddenly remembered urgent appointments and had to dash away again."

Hogwart's variant simply made muggles see a set of ruins and more than likely either made them too scared to explore the grounds, physically blocked them from trespassing, or had some other mental-based trickery that diverted them from prying. It could be a case of all of the above as its hinted Hogwarts had very complex layers of protection in place that only the Headmasters were able to lift.

Comment: This is a great start to an answer!  Do you have sources for this or did you reason it out on your own?

Comment: The answer above yours already explains this in more detail with full references. What do you feel this answer contributes that wasn't already there?